# Java - Tweet Counter

Tags: java, regex, twitter

I have made an application which prints 500 latest tweets when given a keyword, e.g. "cats".

I want to split all the words in the tweets using a `String.split()` with regular expressions and then use a `HashMap` to store each word and use a loop to increment the Integer value of each word, each times its mentioned in tweets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 Streams:

```
String[] words = tweetText.split(" ");
Map<String, Integer> wordCount = Arrays.stream(words)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(word -> word, word -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

If you want to do it case in-sensitive:

```
Map<String, Integer> wordCount = Arrays.stream(words)
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(word -> word, word -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

To find only specific words:

```
Map<String, Integer> wordCount = Arrays.stream(words)
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .filter(word -> wordsToMatch.contains(word))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(word -> word, word -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

Where wordsToMatch can be a Set or List of words you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like :

```
    for (String word : tweetText.split("\\s+")) {
       wordMap.put(word, wordMap.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);
    }
```

`wordMap.getOrDefault(word, 0)` might only be available with java 8. The code will split your tweet into separate words and count the words for each tweet thanks to your map.

Answer (score 0):

I would extend `HashMap<String, Integer>` to provide a `put(key)` that uses the value as a counter :

```
class WordCounter extends HashMap<String, Integer> {

    public void put(String key) { 
        Integer number = this.get(key);
        this.put(key, number == null ? 1 : number + 1);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        WordCounter wc = new WordCounter();
        for(String word : "this is a test and this is too".split(" ")) {
            wc.put(word);
        }
        System.out.println(wc);
    }
}
```

Outputs :

```
{a=1, test=1, too=1, and=1, this=2, is=2}
```